# Qt segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I must develop a social network simulator using C++ and QT library.
I store user into mysql database using QODBC.
When i run my application, i throw a SIGSEGV error.

here, my function which throw this error :

```
QMutex userMutex;
userMutex.lock();

QListIterator<User*> i(users);
User* user;
QString sql = "insert into t_user (id, pseudo, name, firstname, birthdate) values ";
QString bindValue = QString::fromStdString("(?, ?, ?, ?, ?),").repeated(users.count());
sql.append(bindValue);
QSqlQuery query = QSqlQuery(Interface::getCnx());
query.prepare(sql);
while(i.hasNext())
{
    user = i.next();
    query.addBindValue(QString::number(user->getId()));
    query.addBindValue(user->getPseudo());
    query.addBindValue(user->getName());
    query.addBindValue(user->getFirstname());
    QString birthdate = QString::number(user->getBirthDate().year()) + "-" + QString::number(user->getBirthDate().month()) + "-" + QString::number(user->getBirthDate().day());
    query.addBindValue(birthdate);
}
query.exec();

userMutex.unlock();
```

It is "query.exec()" line which throw this error.

Do you see what's wrong?

Comment: Try using some debugger (e.g.  `gdb`) after having compiled with debugging and all warnings (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`)

Comment: take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer ... i guess.
This SIGSEGV error has disappeared when i decrease the size of the list.
Before the list contains 1000 users but now it constains only 800 users per call to this méthod.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have an extra comma here:

```
QString bindValue = QString::fromStdString("(?, ?, ?, ?, ?),").repeated(users.count());
```

So or you "repeat" string count-1 times and then add "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)":

```
QString bindValue = QString::fromStdString("(?, ?, ?, ?, ?),").repeated(users.count() - 1);
bindValue "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Or you have to remove last char of your string bindValue.

Comment: I replace the last coma using the replace method of QString.